# Vb.Net add rowUpdate event for two adapters

Tags: vb.net, events, save, tableadapter

have a look to the relation[image]

I am trying to implement a car lease system. This is part of the relation and not the full relation. This relation says that car can be insured many times but also it has a current insurance ID. The table carInsurance and carInsurance_1 are same tables but ms access show that relation as in the picture. carID and insID are auto-increment fields.
I am loading data from database and use two binding sources: bsCar and bsInsurance to navigate through data. When I press save I save the new car and get the new carID for this car from the database. Then save the carInsurance and again try to get the last insID for this insurance. then update the car again by setting the car.insID to the last insID saved in the carInsurance table.

When I add new car and try save, there a problem happens. The event NewRowInserted will be added to bsCar and not bsInsurance. Every time I debug the program I always get the new carID and never the new insID. Also when dibuging using F11 the event is not fired for the

```
daInsurance.Update(dsDataSet.Tables("insurance"))
```

Below is the full code:

```
Public Class frmCar


    Dim oledbConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dsDataSet As DataSet

    Dim daCar As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim bsCar As BindingSource
    Dim cbCar As OleDbCommandBuilder

    Dim daInsurance As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim bsInsurance As BindingSource
    Dim cbInsurance As OleDbCommandBuilder

    Private Sub frmCar_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            dsDataSet = New DataSet
            loadCars()

            bsCar = New BindingSource(dsDataSet, "car")
            bsInsurance = New BindingSource(dsDataSet, "insurance")

            CarIDTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "carId"))
            BrandTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "brand"))
            ModelTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "model"))
            RegNoTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "regNo"))
            InsIDTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "insId"))
            ....

            InsIDTextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsInsurance, "insId"))
            CarIDTextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsInsurance, "carId"))
            InsFromDateDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsInsurance, "insFromDate"))
           ...

            dgvInsurance.DataSource = bsInsurance ' dsDataSet.Tables("insurance")
            bsInsurance.Filter = "carId=" & CarIDTextBox.Text
            bsInsurance.Position = bsInsurance.Find("insId", InsIDTextBox.Text)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub loadCars()
        Dim sql As String

        Try
            oledbConn = New OleDbConnection(oledbConnString)
            oledbConn.Open()

            sql = "select * from car order by carId"
            daCar = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oledbConn)
            daCar.Fill(dsDataSet, "car")
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------

            sql = "select * from carInsurance order by carId"
            daInsurance = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oledbConn)
            daInsurance.Fill(dsDataSet, "insurance")
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------

            oledbConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            oledbConn.Close()
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub    

    Private Sub btnNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
        Try
            bsCar.AddNew()
            bsInsurance.AddNew()
            bsInsurance.Filter = "carId=0"

            carMode = "newCar"
            insMode = "newInsurance"

            FullInsuranceCheckBox.Checked = False
            ThirdPartyCheckBox.Checked = False
            InsideOmanCheckBox.Checked = False
            InsideUAECheckBox.Checked = False

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        Dim newCarID As Integer
        Dim newInsID As Integer

        If carMode = "newCar" Then
            Try

                AddHandler daCar.RowUpdated, New OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler(AddressOf NewRowInserted)
                AddHandler daInsurance.RowUpdated, New OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler(AddressOf NewRowInserted)

                Me.Validate()
                bsCar.EndEdit()
                cbCar = New OleDbCommandBuilder(daCar)
                daCar.Update(dsDataSet.Tables("car"))

                newCarID = newID

                CarIDTextBox.Text = newCarID
                CarIDTextBox1.Text = newCarID    

                'bsInsurance.EndEdit()
                cbInsurance = New OleDbCommandBuilder(daInsurance)
                daInsurance.Update(dsDataSet.Tables("insurance"))

                newInsID = newID
                InsIDTextBox.Text = newInsID
                InsIDTextBox1.Text = newInsID

                RemoveHandler daCar.RowUpdated, AddressOf NewRowInserted
                RemoveHandler daInsurance.RowUpdated, AddressOf NewRowInserted

                daCar.Update(dsDataSet.Tables("car"))

                MsgBox("Car saved successfully")

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(Err.Description)
            End Try

        End If

    End Sub

    Sub NewRowInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs)
        ' Check if we are working for a row with the proper state
        If e.Row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Then
            Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", e.Command.Connection)
            newID = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That's a dodgy schema in my opinion.  The car table should not have an ID for the current carInsurance record.  The current carInsurance record is determined by date, surely.  I think that you should have a separate view that shows the current insurance for each car based on date.

Comment: That is good point, but I may find a problem that needs to be solved this way. I am just wondering why bsInsurance does not fire the rowUpdated event when update method is called. I know the database design is not the best but why this happens?

Comment: I see, I think the event is not fired because it actually not saving the insurance to the database